# What can be the all possible scenarios that make uiview jump up 20px

Tags: ios, uiview

...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

...

This is the code inside my app delegate which is loading a viewcontroller (or root view controller). This viewcontroller performs some checks and load another view according to checks.

But the views loaded by viewcontroller is jumping 20px up, i searched a lot regarding this, mostly status bar is blamed, so I tried to hide it, but no use.

Please clear me one more thing whats the difference between initWithNibName and init seems like both doing same job.

After searching a lot and still not getting any solution thats why i want to know, What can be the all possible scenarios that make uiview jump up 20px

...manually adjusting the view size is not a good practice in this case. I want to hunt down the actual cause of this jumping so the problem can be fixed in a standard way not with hacks.

Comment: what's the size of your viewController (view) that you have set in the .xib file (in Interface Builder)? it's possibly 20px smaller in height than the screen height is.

Comment: view size in IB is 320 * 460 and not editable.

Answer (score 2):

Difference in `initWithNibName` and `init` for a viewController is that `initWithNibName` you can specify any name for this viewController nib file, where init only searches for specific nib names to load

For example,
If your viewController name is `MyViewController`, then when you call init, the nib controller with name `MyViewController.xib` is searched and loaded
Where if you call `initWithNibName`, you can specify any nib name

about the jumping issue, i am too guessing that is a status bar issue, please present more information

Comment: Thanks for clearing my confusion regarding init and initwithnibname, i am also confused where to track this issue and what info should i provide, please tell me is this info of any worth "view size in IB is 320 * 460 and not editable".

Comment: did u hide the status bar, what is the autoresizeMask you have on your view, how do you add ur view on the main View